# Reference Requests Regarding Names of Particular Objects (functions, theorems, et al.)

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions

I'm interested in knowing if there is a name to the solution I found for a particular functional equation. What is the best (most considerate / practical / efficient) way of asking such a question on MSE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a tag, [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology), for questions like these (so, use it on your question). I would suggest giving a sufficient amount of detail on your functional equation and the solution you obtained, to ease the work for potential answerers.